# Dynamic configuration to setup filename and directory in Camel SFTP

Tags: apache-camel

I am working on setting up SFTP configuration globally with endpoint component available in Camel but unable to do it and ended up with creating multiple endpoints for the same SFTP server.
Below is the code.

```
<endpoint id="sftpPollCSVFile"
    uri="sftp://user@localhost:22/input/test">
    <property key="password" value="password" />
    <property key="include"
        value=".csv" />
    <property key="streamDownload" value="true" />
</endpoint>
<endpoint id="sftpWriteFileToTest1"
    uri="sftp://user@localhost:22/output/test1">
    <property key="password" value="password" />
    <property key="fileName"
        value="test1.csv" />
</endpoint>
<endpoint id="sftpWriteFileToTest2"
    uri="sftp://user@localhost:22/output/test2">
    <property key="password" value="password" />
    <property key="fileName"
        value="test2.csv" />
</endpoint>
```

Currently, I using 3.7.5 version of Camel. As Camel SFTP has this syntax - sftp://host:port/directoryName, it is not allowing to add the property or header in directory name.

Let me know whether I need to use an other component other than endpoint component in order to define my SFTP configuration only once to reuse the same connection rather than defining multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `recursive` query parameter to include all files under input or output and its sub-folders then use `include` or `includeExt` parameters to limit which files get included.